# lvl size question

Tags: framing

I am building a 16'x24'shed style roof addition to the side of an existing shed.the pitch is a 2/12.rafters are 2x10x16'on 24" centers.the length of the lvl will be 24' clear span supported by a 6x6 post at each end with a 3-1/2" notch to support 2) 1-3/4" x 18" lvls. I should also mention the rafters will be side loaded to the lvl with joist hangers.The roof will be sheated with 5/8 osb, The roofing material will be the lap style metal with face screws. All of the Boise Cascade charts i have looked at start at 20'. i have gotten no reply from Carters Lumbers engineer.could I get away with the 16" lvls since my rafter span is only 16'?

Comment: It has been years since I have done it, but the suppliers like Boise Cascade have in house engineers that can answer specific application questions. I have used their knowledge twice (different vendors), once 15 years or so ago and most recently about 8 years ago.

Comment: "14 to 16 inches deep and 3.5 inches wide" https://civilsir.com/what-size-lvl-header-for-12-16-14-10-8-foot-span/ - Snow load though? You go with 20" and no one has to do any homework. Apparently 16" (even 14") will do but 18" is what they told you, because anything that happens *isn't going to be their fault*. You call 'em up, they're going to say 18" again. You're asking the internet what you can get away with.